# How does Win 7 SndVol Mixer work? What WinAPI Functions are used in it?

Tags: winapi, function, audio, dll, autohotkey

So I was wondering what Windows API functions I'd need to use to get info as in this pic (SndVol Mixer). What's yellow highlighted is more interesting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeQhQ.png (The Image)

That's the Applications that have audio waveOutput, also reading its audio meter output. When it becomes active. Then also acquiring the volume from the Applications.

Now I'd like to be able doing this through the winmm.dll or internal Windows API calls.
As I'll be writing the app using AHK (AutoHotKeys)

Here's a few function i belive are relevant:

waveOutGetNumDevs

waveOutGetID

or

mixerGetNumDevs

mixerGetID

The system used is Win 7. If you can forward me to any sort of tutorials where functions are used. I would be very happy.

This is what I've read some what:

http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23792

Answer (score 1):

The wave/mixer/multimedia API has been deprecated in Vista+ and is limited in scope to your own application.
To use the new features in Vista+, you need to look at the [Core Audio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370784%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: So I've found this VA.ahk function Lib for AHK http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23792